# How to create pop up in phone gap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

i want to create a pop up window in phonegap jquery. Please help me out. i need click a button then it shows a popup that i have atached.[image: This is the figure that i want to create using phonegap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can overlay above the status bar (time, battery info).
But if that isn't the problem... just add a div with an absolute position.

```
#myDiv {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   z-index: 10;
   display: none;
}

<body>
 <div id='myDiv'>
 <!-- add the fields/buttons here -->
 </div>
</body>

<script>
  //jQuery script
 $('#myDiv').show();
</script>
```

Comment: yea ,. we don't want to hide status bar (: let me try your code